# Preferencefragment as DialogFragment needs a toolbar (compliant with design library)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-preferences

I show my App's preferences via a PreferenceFragment that is a DialogFragment. Works very nice 99%.

How can I add a toolbar to that specific DialogFragment?

The layout is loaded via addPreferencesFromResource( R.xml.preferences).

So, I don't have a layout I can add a toolbar to.

**Edit:** below I found a good solution!!

Comment: Why is this not a good question? Can you elaborate?

Comment: are you asking about adding dialog to the dialog fragment?

Comment: Thanks for replying. 
The DialogFragment contains a PreferenceFragment. 
I would like to add the toolbar ... for 2 reasons: (1) conformity to other screens having a toolbar and especially (2) the empty toolbar will show the 'back' arrow.

Comment: sorry @tjm1706. I misspelled in the above comment. its not dialog. its dialog title. But in your above comment you mentioned about backbutton in the toolbar. You don't need to use a toolbar. Instead you create a custom layout view with back button. and use the `onclicklistener` of that view to update the rest of the fragment. Check the below answer. If you have any doubt add a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a much better solution.

First I use the a PreferenceFragment that is fit for the support library. Author Christophe Beyls (thank you!).

**Step 1**: Base class: PreferenceFragment for the support library

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.preference.PreferenceScreen;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

/* A PreferenceFragment f/t support library. @author Christophe Beyls */
public abstract class PreferenceFragment2 extends DialogFragment {

    private static final int FIRST_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private static final int MSG_BIND_PREFERENCES = 1;
    private static final int MSG_REQUEST_FOCUS = 2;
    private static final String PREFERENCES_TAG = "android:preferences";
    private static final float HC_HORIZONTAL_PADDING = 16;

    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case MSG_BIND_PREFERENCES:
                bindPreferences();
                break;
            case MSG_REQUEST_FOCUS:
                mList.focusableViewAvailable(mList);
                break;
            }
        }
   };

    private boolean mHavePrefs;
    private boolean mInitDone;
    private ListView mList;
    private PreferenceManager mPreferenceManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle( android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.FullScreenDialogTheme);
        try {
            Constructor<PreferenceManager> c = PreferenceManager.class.getDeclaredConstructor( Activity.class, int.class);
            c.setAccessible(true);
            mPreferenceManager = c.newInstance(this.getActivity(), FIRST_REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ListView listView = new ListView(getActivity());
        listView.setId(android.R.id.list);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            final int horizontalPadding = (int) (HC_HORIZONTAL_PADDING * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
            listView.setPadding(horizontalPadding, 0, horizontalPadding, 0);
        }
        return listView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        if (mHavePrefs) {
            bindPreferences();
        }

        mInitDone = true;

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            Bundle container = savedInstanceState.getBundle(PREFERENCES_TAG);
            if (container != null) {
                final PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen = getPreferenceScreen();
                if (preferenceScreen != null) {
                    preferenceScreen.restoreHierarchyState(container);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {
            Method m = PreferenceManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("dispatchActivityStop");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            m.invoke(mPreferenceManager);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public void onDestroyView() {
        mList = null;
        mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        try {
            Method m = PreferenceManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("dispatchActivityDestroy");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            m.invoke(mPreferenceManager);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen = getPreferenceScreen();
        if (preferenceScreen != null) {
            Bundle container = new Bundle();
            preferenceScreen.saveHierarchyState(container);
            outState.putBundle(PREFERENCES_TAG, container);
        }
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            Method m = PreferenceManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("dispatchActivityResult", int.class, int.class, Intent.class);
            m.setAccessible(true);
            m.invoke(mPreferenceManager, requestCode, resultCode, data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public PreferenceManager getPreferenceManager() {
        return mPreferenceManager;
    }

    public void setPreferenceScreen(PreferenceScreen screen) {
        try {
            Method m = PreferenceManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("setPreferences", PreferenceScreen.class);
            m.setAccessible(true);
            boolean result = (Boolean) m.invoke(mPreferenceManager, screen);
            if (result && (screen != null)) {
                mHavePrefs = true;
                if (mInitDone) {
                    postBindPreferences();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public PreferenceScreen getPreferenceScreen() {
        try {
            Method m = PreferenceManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("getPreferenceScreen");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            return (PreferenceScreen) m.invoke(mPreferenceManager);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void addPreferencesFromIntent(Intent intent) {
        requirePreferenceManager();
        try {
            Method m = PreferenceManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("inflateFromIntent", Intent.class, PreferenceScreen.class);
            m.setAccessible(true);
            PreferenceScreen screen = (PreferenceScreen) m.invoke(mPreferenceManager, intent, getPreferenceScreen());
            setPreferenceScreen(screen);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public void addPreferencesFromResource(int resId) {
        requirePreferenceManager();
        try {
            Method m = PreferenceManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("inflateFromResource", Context.class, int.class, PreferenceScreen.class);
            m.setAccessible(true);
            PreferenceScreen screen = (PreferenceScreen) m.invoke(mPreferenceManager, getActivity(), resId, getPreferenceScreen());
            setPreferenceScreen(screen);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public Preference findPreference(CharSequence key) {
        if (mPreferenceManager == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return mPreferenceManager.findPreference(key);
    }

    private void requirePreferenceManager() {
        if (this.mPreferenceManager == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("This should be called after super.onCreate.");
        }
    }

    private void postBindPreferences() {
        if (!mHandler.hasMessages(MSG_BIND_PREFERENCES)) {
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_BIND_PREFERENCES);
        }
    }

    private void bindPreferences() {
        final PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen = getPreferenceScreen();
        if (preferenceScreen != null) {
            preferenceScreen.bind(getListView());
        }
    }

    public ListView getListView() {
        ensureList();
        return mList;
    }

    private void ensureList() {
        if (mList != null) {
            return;
        }
        View root = getView();
        if (root == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Content view not yet created");
        }
        View rawListView = root.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        if (!(rawListView instanceof ListView)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class");
        }
        mList = (ListView) rawListView;
        if (mList == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'");
        }
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_REQUEST_FOCUS);
    }
}
```

**Step 2**: Create your own FragmentPreferences based on the above file:

**Step 2.1** - Create a layout file: res/layout/preferences_with_toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/preferences_dialog"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/preferences_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:itemTextColor="#333"
        app:itemIconTint="#333"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Step 2.2** - Create the menu options in the toolbar. None in my case.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
</menu>
```

**Step 2.3** - Create your FragmentPreferences

```
public class FragmentUserPreferences extends PreferenceFragment2 implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    View rootView = null; 
    Preference letterSizePref;

@Override
public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Access the main layout file
    rootView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.preferences_with_toolbar, container, false);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById( R.id.preferences_toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_back);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });
    toolbar.inflateMenu( R.menu.dialog_toolbar_empty);
    toolbar.setTitle("Preferences");
    View view = super.onCreateView( inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( getActivity()).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener( this);
    LinearLayout prefLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById( R.id.preferences_dialog);
    prefLayout.addView( view);

    // Load the preferences from an XML resource
    addPreferencesFromResource( R.xml.preferences);

    letterSizePref= (Preference) findPreference( "letterSize");

    // From here this is your default user settings stuff 
    // ... 
    return rootView; 
}
// etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to create custom layout for the dialog fragment like below.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/orange"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_36dp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:hint="@string/first_name"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ok"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OK"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/holo_green_light"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CANCEL"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/holo_red_light"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

To use cardview which will give you a shadow functionality looks like a toolbar use the following dependency in your build.gradle of your app.

> compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'

2. Create a custom dialog fragment which uses the above layout like below.

```
public class CustomDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    public CustomDialogFragment(){

    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle onSavedInstanceState){
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(onSavedInstanceState);

        // Hide default title.
        dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle onSavedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_layout, container, false);

        ImageView backButton = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.back_button);

        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /** TODO handle the Back button (OR)
                    Communicate to the MainActivity to dismiss the dialog
                    To know more about communicating from fragment to main activity check this thread
                    http://stackoverflow.com/a/34498055/3049065
                 **/
            }
        });

        Button okButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.ok);

        okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO handle the ok Button
            }
        });

        Button cancelButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.cancel);

        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO handle the cancel Button
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
}
```

Check this below branch of my repository for a demo project.

https://github.com/Mahendran-Sakkarai/Testing-Android-Applications/tree/CustomDialogFragment

The output will be like below.
[image: Custom Fragment with backbutton]