# Access main activity view from fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an activity that has container that contain fragments and this fragment has other fragments.

Now I want this second or child fragment to access views in main activity, but it returns null pointer exception.

class:

```
public class ImageListFragment extends AbsListViewBaseFragment   implements  ObservableScrollViewCallbacks {

public static final int INDEX = 0;




android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton mFab;

@Bind(R.id.ic_call)
ImageView mIcCall;
@Bind(R.id.ic_email)
ImageView mIcEmail;
@Bind(R.id.ic_forum)
ImageView mIcForum;
FabToolbar mFabToolbar;
ObservableListView mObservableListView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_image_list, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    ((ListView) listView).setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));

    final SubTaB mainActivity = (SubTaB)getActivity();
    ButterKnife.bind(mainActivity);
      //////////////// problem here 
     mFabToolbar = (FabToolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fabtoolbar);  
      ////////////////
    getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TAG");
        //  rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    mObservableListView = (ObservableListView)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    //


     mObservableListView.setAdapter(this.listView.getAdapter());
   mObservableListView.setScrollViewCallbacks(this);



    mainActivity.mFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(mainActivity.getApplicationContext(), "msg msg", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mainActivity.mFabToolbar.expandFab();
        }
    });



    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            startImagePagerActivity(position);
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    AnimateFirstDisplayListener.displayedImages.clear();
}

private static class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final String[] IMAGE_URLS = Constants.IMAGES;

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ImageLoadingListener animateFirstListener = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();

    private DisplayImageOptions options;

    ImageAdapter(Context context) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_stub) // تغيير الفيو قبل تحميل الصورة
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty) // لما الصورة فاضية
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error) // عند الفشل
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .displayer(new CircleBitmapDisplayer(Color.WHITE, 5))
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return IMAGE_URLS.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_image, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText("Item " + (position + 1));



        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(IMAGE_URLS[position], holder.image, options, animateFirstListener);

        return view;
    }
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
    ImageView image;
}



@Override
public void onScrollChanged(int i, boolean b, boolean b1) {

}

@Override
public void onDownMotionEvent() {

}

@Override
public void onUpOrCancelMotionEvent(ScrollState scrollState) {
    Log.d("","Scroll scroll scroll");

    if (scrollState == ScrollState.UP) {
        mFabToolbar.slideOutFab();
    } else if (scrollState == ScrollState.DOWN) {
        mFabToolbar.slideInFab();
    }
}

@OnClick(R.id.fab)
void onFabClick() {
    mFabToolbar.expandFab();
}

@OnClick(R.id.call)
void onClickCall() {
    iconAnim(mIcCall);
}

@OnClick(R.id.ic_email)
void onClickEmail() {
    iconAnim(mIcEmail);
}

@OnClick(R.id.ic_forum)
void onClickForum() {
    iconAnim(mIcForum);
}

private void iconAnim(View icon) {
    Animator iconAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(
            icon,
            PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", 1f, 1.5f, 1f),
            PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 1f, 1.5f, 1f));
    iconAnim.start();
}







private static class AnimateFirstDisplayListener extends SimpleImageLoadingListener {

    static final List<String> displayedImages = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());

    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        if (loadedImage != null) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
            boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
            if (firstDisplay) {
                FadeInBitmapDisplayer.animate(imageView, 500);
                displayedImages.add(imageUri);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not good practise to find and control a view in this way. Views can easily become detached from activities and cause unexpected exceptions.

You should rather look at using callbacks to communicate between fragments and activities if required. That way, it also keeps your code in the correct places - so the activity is the only one touching its own views and the fragment also only touches its own views. It merely tells the activity (via callbacks) that something has happened that the activity might want to know about. It also ensures that the fragments are completely self contained and can be easily reused.

You can read about how to implement callbacks here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: i want to do this cuz i have FAB in Activity and i want to get all clicks on it in any fragment how i can do this ?

Comment: Have a look at the section titled : "Deliver a Message to a Fragment" in the link above

Answer (score 2):

Use `EventBus` to communicate between the activity and the fragment. `riggarro` suggestion is the correct way. But you can also able to update the base activity views using the `EventBus`.

For example we need to update a `TextView` text in a activity from the fragment, follow the steps.

1. First you need to add the **following library as dependency** to your project in `build.gradle` of your `app`.

> compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'

2. First you need to **create a Event Object class** to communicate between the fragment and activity like below.

> ```
> public class UpdateTextEvent {
>     private String sampleTextValue;
>     public UpdateTextEvent(String textValue) {
>         this.sampleTextValue = textValue;
>     }
>     public String getTextValue() {
>         return sampleTextValue;
>     }
> }
> ```

3. You need to **post a event to the event bus in the fragment** to update the `TextView` in the activity.

> ```
> public class TestingFragment extends Fragment{
>     private EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault()
>     public TextingFragment(){}
>     public void onCreate(Bundle onSavedInstanceState){
>         super.onCreate(onSavedInstanceState);
>     }
>     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState){
>         View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_activity, parent, false);
>         ...
>         Button b1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
>         b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View v) {
>                 //trigger a update to the activity
>                 bus.post(new UpdateTextEvent("testing"));
>             }
>         });
>     }
> }
> ```

4. After that you need to **register the bus with the callback of the event** in the activity like below.

> ```
> public class MainActivity extends Activity{
>     private EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();
>     private TextView textView;
>     @Override
>     public void onCreate(Bundle onSavedInstanceState){
>         super.onCreate(onSavedInstanceState);
>         ....
>         // The textview going to be updated on posting the event
>         textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
>         bus.register(this);
>     }
>     public void onEvent(UpdateTextEvent event){
>         textView.setText(event.getTextValue());
>     }
> }
> ```

In this above example the `onEvent` method will be called when you post a event from the fragment..

Hope it will help you.